# prevent a second aes() to override the range of the axes (ylim, xlim) in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have prices over time for different types of products. I want to visualize the evolution of different prices in one single sheet, so I am using a faceted ggplot. Here's my toy example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(time = rep(1:100, times = 5), 
                  type = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), each = 100), 
                  price = rnorm(n = 500, mean = 100))

gp <- ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = time, y = price))
# scales free because the price level of each product may be different
gp <- gp + facet_wrap(~type, nrow = 3, ncol = 2, scales = "free")
gp <- gp + geom_point() + geom_line()
gp
```

This produces the plot I want:

[image]

I also have reference prices for each type of product (in a different data set), and I want to indicate those prices in the plot. So I am using `geom_hline()` as follows:

```
df2 <- data.frame(type = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 
                  refprice = c(100, 105, 95, 50, 40))
gp <- gp + geom_hline(data = df2, aes(yintercept = refprice), facets = ~type)
```

[image]

It works, but it can substantially change the range of the y-axis, and I do not want that. I'd like to keep the `ylim` as automatically generated by the first part, so as to properly visualize the evolution of the prices regardless of the reference price (it is ok not to see the reference price if it is not relatively close to the actual prices).

I know I can use `scale_y_continuous()`, `coord_cartesian()` or the short-hand `ylim()` to manually set the limits as I want, but I dislike this alternative because either requires hard-coding the limits or too much coding to calculate the appropriate limits. So I thought there must be a simpler and more elegant way in ggplot to avoid the second call to override `ylim`s and instead take advantage of the `ylim`s generated in the first call.

I have been searching (I think, thoroughly) for solutions to this issue (SO, google, rseek, ), and all I find involves the solutions I've just said I dislike. So I decided to post it here to see if someone knows some hidden (or not so hidden) feature in `ggplot2` to make this easier and more elegant. Many thanks.

Comment: this is using ylim but at least it seems to match the scales generated automatically and does not require any further calculations  `+ ylim(min(df1$price), max(df1$price))`

Comment: Thx. This solution does not work for me tough, because each plot (facet) may have very different price levels (that's why I need scales = "free" to allow different ranges in the axes of each plot), and `ylim(min(df1$price), max(df1$price))` imposes a common range to all y-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yrange <- sapply(ggplot_build(gp)$panel$ranges, function(x) x$y.range)
#order df2 correctly (the same order as the panels) if it isn't

gp + geom_hline(data = df2[df2$refprice >= yrange[1,] & df2$refprice <= yrange[2,],], 
                aes(yintercept = refprice))
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thanks. Clever!, to plot only those observations within the desired range. Although it works in the sense that it produces the output I am looking for, this solution falls in the group of solutions that I do not like for this case (because it involves to much coding -too many lines-). Maybe I simplified my toy example too much, and in this example it does not seem you have to include a lot of lines of code, but in my real application I have other horizontal lines, whose color depends on the reference price, so I cannot simply discard those observations outside of the relevant range.

Comment: @HernandoCasas I changed it to work with "free" scales.

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it. Complicated aims require some coding.